# Git flow share hotfix branch

Tags: git, git-flow

Can I share a hotfix branch in git flow? In other words: push it to origin and let some other developer do some changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, its like any other branch simply push it to your remote repository as you do with any other branch.

Git flow is running on your local repository, it doesn't matter what is the name of the branch. in your case it will be hotfix/xxxxx and the other developer simply need to do a `git fetch` on his machine and he will get the branch.